# How to force tensorflow tensors to be symmetric?

Tags: tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, symmetric

I have a set of MxM **symmetric** matrix Variables in a graph whose values I'd like to optimize.

*Is there a way to enforce the symmetric condition?*

I've thought about adding a term to the loss function to enforce it, but this seems awkward and roundabout. What I'd hoped for is something like `tf.matmul(A,B,symmA=True)`
where only a triangular portion of A would be used and learned. Or maybe something like `tf.upperTriangularToFull(A)` which would create a dense matrix from a triangular part.

Answer (score 3):

What if you do `symA = 0.5 * (A + tf.transpose(A))`? It is inefficient but at least it's symmetric.

Comment: That would create the desired symmetry, yes.  I was hoping to benefit from a reduction in variables