# Is there a way to enforce constraints on the elements of variables in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Recently I have been developing a CNN that learns to play the game of GO which I am developing in Tensorflow v0.11.

I read this paper : [Teaching Deep Convolutional Neural Networks to Play Go](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.3409v2.pdf) in which they have enforced symmetry constraints on the convolution weights. I wished to implement that and test the results for myself. I have searched extensively and have been unable to find a good efficient way to do this. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697736/how-to-force-tensorflow-tensors-to-be-symmetric). However much I tried to see a way to enforce a way to enforce these symmetries while training I could not find a way.

Has anyone done something similar before?

Answer (score 2):

One way to enforce symmetry is to store asymmetric weights and make a transformation to make them symmetric before using them. For example, if I want symmetry across the diagonal of a matrix, using (0.5 * weights * tf.transpose(weights)) will give me that. Other permutations will give you other types of symmetry, and these are all differentiable.

Comment: My question to you is - When I am training the network what would the behaviour of the backpropogation be? Would it train the weights correctly? I will try this out none the less. I just wanted to know if you knew.

Comment: Reparametrization tricks always do the right thing with backprop, at the expense of adding computation.

Comment: I would sum rather than multiplying though. `0.5*(weights + tf.transpose(weights)`. Moreover if the matrices are batched with shape [batch_size, N,N] you can use `tf.linalg.transpose` that operates on batched matrices.